# How to install the latest version of mongodb for Windows?

Tags: mongodb

I used the installer v3.0.3 for x64 located at https://www.mongodb.org/downloads, but when I run mongo.exe it claims that: "MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6"

When I run "mongod.exe --version" it claims that "db version v2.0.6".

I don't know why the versions missmatch like that and there is no other installer that I can see. Can anyone help me to properly install the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are multiple versions of mongod.exe copied when using the installer:

- C:\Program Files\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --> v2.0.6
- C:\Program Files\mongodb\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe --> v3.0.3

The tutorials only mention the first one, which lead me astray.

Comment: I think you must have had a previous version installed in that directory already. As far as I'm aware, there was no official MSI installer for MongoDB until 2.6.x .. which also means the installers aren't aware of any prior versions that might have been installed manually.